# Rancid smell using tankless water heater

Tags: water, heater, tankless

We have had our tankless water heater for 5 years, within the last year we have noticed a bad smell coming out of exhaust pipe. The water heater was not vented through the roof instead it vented into the front of the house. We can still smell it with the windows and doors closed. I tried using 2 inch PVC pipe and venting it up under the eave but lengthening the pipe is causing the hot water to turn lukewarm and the smell is still present.There is no smell around the water heater.Any suggestions?

Comment: Brand/model of the heater? How about a few pictures of the installation? You can [edit] that into your question.

Comment: Is this a gas heater?  Rancid smell like rotting eggs is bad as in a gas leak/gas not burning completely.  If so this is in the level of get out and call fire and/or gas company problem.